# How to write portable code for embedded system using embedded C which works on 2 microcontroller?

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, stm32f4

I have a UART Code for STM32F4 DISC-1, I want it to work on other microcontrollers as well. How to begin?

Comment: "Other microcontroles" in the STM32 family? Or for completely different MCU architectures? And typically, there should typically be proper UART examples for each MCU from the manufacturer.

Comment: I think this question is about how to manage / structure core and should be a perfectly fine question to ask here.

Answer (score 5):

You need to write a hardware abstraction layer (HAL)<sup>1)</sup> on top of the drivers , so that you can keep the same caller code, higher layer protocol handling etc, no matter MCU used. Something like (pseudo code):

```
// uart.h

void uart_init ( /* system_clock, desired baudrate, stop bits etc */)

uart_err_t uart_send (const uint8_t* data, size_t size);

uart_err_t uart_receive (uint8_t* data, size_t buf_size, size_t* bytes_received);
```

And so on. The driver for each MCU implements the above functions. This needs to sit on top on all low level stuff like interrupts, ring buffers or DMA - that needs to be handled internally in the driver. The above functions should be interrupt-safe setter/getters.

---

<sup>1)</sup> Not to be confused with ST's bloatware so-called "HAL" which shouldn't be used for any purpose. Do look at it for hints how to implement the drivers, but don't use their code as-is.